# Iterating td's for getting values from database

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker, while-loop

I've got few iterations through the database like:

```
<?php
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='1'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' id='datepicker' /></td>";
      echo "<td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
?>

<?php
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='2'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' id='datepicker' /></td>";
      echo "<td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
?>
```

The problem is with the jQuery datepicker. It works only for the first input, like when the test table returns for example 3 entries (e.g., mysql,datepicker,save; oracle,datepicker,save; db2,datepicker,save), `datepicker` works only for the first input when I click it (like for oracle,datepicker,save) but not for the rest. Any idea how to populate it for every listed input based on table elements in scope of one while?

Comment: Do you mind passing me some code? I'd like to make sure I'll do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of breaking your query to the molecular level, use a single SQL Statement, and a single loop:

```
<?php
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' class='datepicker' /></td>";
  echo "<td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah... that would be most effective and would make my code muuuuch smaller, can you show it it with the complete code for above example? Much appriciated.

Comment: Thanks, but datepicker still works only for the first input :)

Comment: This might be due to the fact you are using an ID instead of class, thus creating multiple elements with the same ID. Try replacing `id=datepicker` with `class=datepicker`. Obviously you'll need to change the JQuery selector as well

Comment: Oh well, now works! :) Thank you. I've used vlcekmi3 remark, changed to .datepicker instead of #datepicker, and used your answer with the class instead of id :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2)");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($test) ) {
  echo "<tr>
          <td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>
          <td><input type='text' class='datepicker' /></td>
          <td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>
        </tr>";
}
// datepicker issue - change unique identifier
<script>
  $(function() { $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); });
</script>
```

**note**: do not use `mysql_**` functions (are deprecated), use e.g. `mysqli_**`

Answer (score 0):

In HTML document id should be unique. Since you are render HTML inside loop several HTML elements can have save id. So that, jQuery selector may get the first matching element since jQuery assumes only one id for the document. You can use class instead of id. Apart from that, don't mix it up the PHP and HTML. Best practice is to keep them seperate as possible

```
<?php $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2)"); ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='datepicker' /></td>
        <td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```